# My server is running on prot 6666, I can get response from postman, but when I open localhost:6666 on browser, it says cannot be reached

Tags: javascript, express

[enter image description here][1]

[enter image description here][2]

[enter image description here][3]

Three images are terminal showing server is running, get "hello" back on postman, but the localhost cannot be reached.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFnQZ.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCkZv.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v80L.png

Answer (score -1):

you will give the ''hello'' this fromat
[enter image description here][0]
Use it after reflected..

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand what you mean. When I tested the backend on postman, everything works, I can get products, create products. but when I try to open the localhost:6666 on my browser, it cannot be opened. And I am trying to make api calls from the frontend, I cannot not get data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).